# MSSQL - fazer select de forma no resultado os campos nao aparecerem repetidos

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O select que estou a fazer é este:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Entity.ComercialName
    ,dbo.ScheduleStatus.Description
    ,dbo.ScheduleGoal.Description AS alias_DSG
    ,dbo.ScheduleType.Description AS alias_DST
    ,dbo.Entity.ID
    ,dbo.Schedule.Notes
    ,dbo.Schedule.DATE
FROM (
    dbo.Schedule RIGHT JOIN dbo.ScheduleStatus ON ScheduleStatus.id = Schedule.ScheduleStatus
    )
RIGHT JOIN dbo.ScheduleGoal ON Schedule.ScheduleGoal = ScheduleGoal.Id
RIGHT JOIN dbo.ScheduleType ON Schedule.ScheduleType = ScheduleType.id
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Entity ON SChedule.Entity = Entity.Id
GROUP BY Entity.ComercialName
    ,ScheduleStatus.Description
    ,ScheduleGoal.Description
    ,ScheduleType.Description
    ,Entity.ID
    ,Schedule.Notes
    ,Schedule.DATE;
```

O resultado que desejo é:

[image: Resultado Final]

Comment: Parece que esse resultado é adquirido no momento da codificação da aparência do relatório, e não diretamente na tabela do banco de dados resultante. No caso programando os eventos de desenho do relatório no código fonte da aplicação.

Comment: Mas você conseguiria fazer isso com um código SQL recursivo usando UNION ALL de um resultado com as primeiras colunas, e um resultado dos demais resultados depois do primeiro, de cada linha do primeiro resultado. Teria que ser SQL dinâmico.

Comment: e como faço isso?
ao fazer o UNION ALL ele vai juntar os campos repetidos?